# How to use promise.all for 2 queries in 1 function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to use Promise.all in this function but I have not used yet so I don't know how to do.

```
async adminCreateGroup(req, res) {
try {
  const {groupCode, groupName} = req.body;
  const members= req.body.members;

  const createGroup= await db.sequelize.query(CALL gojp.AdminCreateGroup('${groupCode}', '{groupName}');,
                {mapToModel: true,type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});

  const { customerGroupCode } = createGroup[0]['0'];

  for(let i = 0; i < customerCodeList.length; i++)
  {
  const createMemberOfGroup = await db.sequelize.query(
    `CALL gojp.createCustomerNGroup('${customerGroupCode}','${members[i]['id']}');`,
               {mapToModel: true, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT} );
  };
  return...
}catch(err){
  return ...;
}
```

When I try with code above, if the 2nd query dies, the 1st query still runs.

Now, I want to use ***Promise.all*** to make sure that all function ***adminCreateGroup*** will stop and throw error if one of 2 queries fails.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: what you describe is transaction, which should be part of database interface.

Comment: It looks like you are using the result of AdminCreateGroup in the queries in the for..loop. You will not be able to run both at the same time if you need results of the first. Quick thought, the queries will still run so this will not work like a transaction (unsure if that's what you meant)

Comment: @clay Yes, I need the result of the 1st for the 2nd. But I am not clear about transaction?

Comment: Research a bit on "database transactions" for whatever server you are using (SQLServer, MySQL, Postgres, etc). A transaction is a group of queries that will either all work, or will "roll back" any previous successes if one fails down the line. (Better explanations abound : ) `Promise.all` is not for that. Are you talking about the queries in the for..loop to run concurrently?

Comment: Oh no, I expect 2 queries run in turn and if one of them fails then the program will stop. At this code, if the 2nd query fail, the 1st still run. It's not my expectation. Can u help me? @clay

Comment: So, let's see you want the result of the 1st for the 2nd. AND you don't want the 1st to run when the 2nd fails. Sorry, but those two requirements are contradictory.